# A word to describe somebody who likes to understand how something works

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that can be used to describe a person who likes to understand how something works and tries to make the same thing in their own way.

Example sentence:

- *Euros is always taking something apart to see how it works ... then she will try to build a better one. She is a real ____.*

Comment: I would say "scientist".

Comment: @HotLicks You’ve got a typo… “scientist” should be “engineer” ;)

Comment: @ColleenV - Same difference

Answer (score 5):

The word *tinkerer* might fit. *To tinker* can mean "to repair, adjust, or work with something in an unskilled or experimental manner" ([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tinker)). It's the "experimental" part that could make it work for your case.

> He's been tinkering with cars since he was a kid, and now he's a *tinkerer* who knows nearly as much as a mechanic. <sup>[[source](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/tinkerer)]</sup>

Comment: I see a superscript but can't find the footnote.  (I like the word, by the way.)

Comment: @aparente001 In a dictionary context, the superscript number might relate to one out of several meanings of a word, instead of referring to a footnote. If that's the case, the number is meaningless in this citation.

Comment: @ygoe No; in a non-historical dictionary, senses are listed in order of currency, so a (7) say will hint strongly at a rare, perhaps confusing, usage.

Comment: @ygoe The superscript number was a link to the original source, and was not taken from the source itself. I have edited the link to make its purpose clearer.